# Rspec-Puppet - how to test metaparameter 'require' of a resource in a Puppet class or defined type?

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

When I have a Puppet class which declares a resource with metaparameter 'require', how do I test this resource and the metaparameter in the spec test?

Excerpt of class showing resource declaration

```
  $patch = 'jboss-eap-7.4.11-patch.zip'
  wildfly::patch::offline { 'Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11':
    source  => "/tmp/${patch}",
    require => Class['wildfly'],
  }
```

This is what I could think of so far, then tested, and failed miserably:

#### Spec test 1st attempt

```
  let(:pre_condition) { ['define wildfly::patch::offline($source) {}'] }
  it do
    is_expected.to contain_wildfly__patch__offline('Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11').with(
      'source' => '/tmp/jboss-eap-7.4.11-patch.zip',
      'require' => 'Class["wildfly"]'
    )
  end
```

#### Error

```
       expected that the catalogue would contain Wildfly::Patch::Offline[Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11] with require set to "Class[\"wildfly\"]" but it is set to Class[Wildfly]{:name=>"Wildfly"}
     # ./spec/classes/jboss_74_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### Spec test correction attempt from the error message

> Weird naming it is, but I trust error messages

```
    is_expected.to contain_wildfly__patch__offline('Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11').with(
      'source' => '/tmp/jboss-eap-7.4.11-patch.zip',
      'require' => 'Class[Wildfly]{:name=>"Wildfly"}'
    )
```

#### New error

```
       expected that the catalogue would contain Wildfly::Patch::Offline[Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11] with require set to "Class[Wildfly]{:name=>\"Wildfly\"}" but it is set to Class[Wildfly]{:name=>"Wildfly"}
     # ./spec/classes/jboss_74_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### Also tried without success

I started frobnicating with different single/double/no quotes, only to get new errors with different quoting.

How do I get past this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dancing around the correct syntax.  To express a resource reference to RSpec-Puppet, you omit quotation marks around the resource title (which in most cases are optional in manifest code anyway).  But RSpec-Puppet's messaging has misled you: the correct form does not include a property list.  The wanted string representation of your resource reference should be simply `'Class[wildfly]'`.  So:

```
    is_expected.to contain_wildfly__patch__offline('Atualiza JBoss para 7.4.11').with(
      'source' => '/tmp/jboss-eap-7.4.11-patch.zip',
      'require' => 'Class[wildfly]'
    )
```

The full rules are documented in [the RSpec-Puppet documentation of the specific tests for resource relationships](https://rspec-puppet.com/documentation/classes/#testing-relationships-between-resources):

> The values [] must be in the format used in the
> Puppet catalogue (which is slightly different to the way they're
> written in a Puppet manifest).
>
> - The resource titles must be unquoted (`Package[apache]` instead of `Package['apache']`)
> - One title per resource (`[Package[apache], Package[htpasswd]]` instead of `Package[apache, htpasswd]`)
> - If referencing a class, it must be fully qualified and should not have a leading :: (`Class[apache::service]` instead of
>   `Class[::apache::service]`)

Note also: resource titles are case sensitive, so it is either significant or erroneous that RSpec is telling you that the relationship is actually on `Class[Wildfly]` (capital 'W') instead of on `Class['wildfly']` (small 'w').  Package and class names *should* be lowercase, so I'm not sure what's going on here, but perhaps it's another RSpec quirk.

Comment: Perfect! 'Class[Wildfly]' did it: single quotes for the whole thing, no quotes for the resource title, and both capitalized. Thanks!
In the end, I used the specific syntax for relationships - .that_requires('Class[Wildfly]') - from the docs you indicated, with the same results. Guess it's more "to the eye".
Thanks!